# Getting the issues from a certain milestone in Github

Tags: github

All I'm looking for is a way to get a list of issues for a given milestone. It looks like Github treats milestones a bit like labels in that you can ask for the labels for an issue, but not the issues for a given label.

I know that I can filter my issues by milestone on the Github website, but this traverses multiple pages and I wanted an easy way to see all of the issues for a milestone in a more printer friendly version.

Any tips?

Comment: The issue filters let you see all issues for a label, or milestone, so I'm not sure what your first paragraph is all about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GitHub's API for this. See [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) on how to get the list of issues for a repo and notice the milestone parameter. The response you will get is a big JSON document, so you would have to create a small script to pull only the titles of the issues, or use grep, or smething like [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Notice also that [API responses are also paged](http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination), but you can set the paging to be 100 entries per page, which is usually enough. If not, you would again have to create a small script to fetch all the pages (or do it manually).

Comment: This is what I ended up having to do. It seemed a bit more roundabout than what I needed. I feel like there should simply be a `getIssuesForMilestone` method, but oh well.

I had problems using the dictionary with the listing of the issues for the repository, so ended up just getting all of the issues and filtering them out afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [GraphQL API which is V4](https://developer.github.com/v4/). and do something like:

```
{
  repository(owner: "X", name: "X") {
    milestone(number: X) {
      id
      issues(first: 100) {
        edges {
          node {
            id,
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find any *easy* methods. This worked a treat for me:

1. `brew install hub` (on OSX). Hub is created by GitHub
2. cd to the local repo you want to access the origin for.
3. `hub issue -M 21 -f "%I,%t,%L,%b,%au,%as" > save_here.csv`
4. profit.

Find the issue # (21 in the example above) in the URL on GitHub when you are viewing the milestone.
Docs for hub and in particular the format (-f) flag can be found here: https://hub.github.com/hub-issue.1.html

Answer (score 0):

First find the list of milestones using [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/issues#milestones)
Then query [this](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/issues#list-issues-for-a-repository) api by milestone number for each milestone

Answer (score 0):

Given a milestone `$title` in `$owner/$repo`, we can list the issues in this milestone using curl and jq:

```
api_url="https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo"
MS=$(curl -s "$api_url/milestones" | jq '.[] | select(.title == "QA")')
MS_number=$(echo "$MS" | jq .number -r)
MS_state=$(echo "$MS" | jq .state -r)

echo "Found $title milestone with state=$MS_state"
echo ""

issues=$(curl -s "$api_url/issues?milestone=$MS_number" | jq '.[].number' -r)
echo "The following issues are in the QA milestone:"
for i in $issues; do
  issue_title=$(curl -s "$api_url/issues/$i"  | jq '.title' -r)
  echo "  https://github/$owner/$repo/issues/$i - $issue_title"
done
echo ""
```